# How to hide all warning popups in chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, popups

In my browser popup occasionally is appearing popup: "Warning: your chromium settings are stored on a network drive..." and i have to click OK.

Can I block this? There is some flags, which hide all warning popups or some setting?

[image]

Comment: Since Chrome's behavior varies from version-to-version, please specify the version you are running (and the OS would also be helpful.) Are you in an enterprise environment with roaming profiles?  Or is %appdata% redirected in some other way?  If so, is the network location a mapped drive or UNC?  Assuming Windows 7 or 10, you can type "set appdata" to see the location.  Also your question's title asks how to hide -all- warning popups, yet in the question itself, you appear to want to suppress only the one about the profile location.

Comment: I have no problem with location network drive or slowdowns. Chrome isn't installed locally and it is turn on from server. I will use --no-sandbox to hide popups. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked from the Chrome developers on Oct 29, 2015
[Issue 103902 - Chrome not working at mounted/network drive](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103902).

The answer was:

> This is working as intended. We do not support running Chrome from a network share because doing so would prevent enabling the sandbox.

The sandbox is what isolates the operating system from malicious software running
inside Chrome. So it would be preferable to store your profile on a regular disk,
rather than running in such an unsafe mode.

Chrome will keep on nagging you until you do, and there is no way to disable this
message besides specifically requesting to disable the sandbox,
using the command line switch `--no-sandbox`.

Comment: Worth pointing out, you can keep the Chrome installation directory on a network drive, but use the local machine for the profile.

Comment: Chrome can certainly be used with roaming profiles in an enterprise environment: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7349337?hl=en . However, the way roaming profiles work, the profile is copied down to the local machine when you log on, then copied back up when you log off.  The "--disable-gpu-sandbox" switch might suppress the error, per https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84045

Comment: Also the discussion at the link provided by @harrymc suggests "--no-sandbox" suppresses the warning message.

Comment: @Debra: Good catch - added that in.

Comment: I have no problem with location network drive or slowdowns. Chrome isn't installed locally and it is turn on from server. I will use --no-sandbox to hide popups. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer has helped solved the problem, please accept the it (tick the V sign).